# JavaScript não funciona na minha extensão do Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão

Estou tentando criar uma simples extensão de teste para o navegador Chrome, onde eu crio um botão que ao ser clicado, mostra uma mensagem dentro de uma `<div>`.

O meu arquivo `manifest.json` atualmente está assim:

```
{
    "name": "Hello World Viewer",
    "version": "0.2.3",
    "description": "A test application",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Abaixo está o meu código HTML junto com o JS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first extension</title>
        <script>
            console.log("JavaScript Running!");
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    document.querySelector("#msg").innerText = "Hello World :)";
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="msg">**********************</div>
        <button id="btn">Click here</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sempre que eu tento clicar no botão através da extensão (o código funciona como página normalmente) nada acontece. Aparentemente o JS não é executado.

Eu coloquei no código esse `console.log()` para verificar se o JS roda, mas a mensagem não é impressa. O que está acontecendo?